# Tutorial for facial animation toplogy?

Tags: animation

I am trying to retopo a face and I would like to animate it, making smooth facial expression if possible.

I'm not a very experienced user but I do my best and try to learn as much as i can. Having a project helps me to get motivated and learn stuff.

I've seen a few tutorials for Retopology on YouTube, I know the basics (the process and avoiding Tri and Ngons) and making loops around the important features. I'd like it in a depth real course to follow along to be sure of what I'm doing, even if it's not a free course I'm fine.

thank you for your help !

Comment: Hi. Tutorial requests are off-topic, but if you can ask a *specific* question about an aspect of this that you are having trouble with, that would be fine.

Comment: When you are stuck on topology, always visit Pinterest for ideas. I always consult Pinterest for topology on faces, hands, ears, feet, legs, etc. There I always tons of topology ideas. If you have no account in Pinterest, you don't know what you're missing there. Pinterest is where you find plentiful pins & boards not only on topology, also on alpha brushes, textures, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a tutorial request (See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic).